# R Shiny HTML Integration

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

For an R Shiny App, I am trying to come with an Intro/Login page which has its UI based on an HTML template. I am able to achieve this as suggested in this link https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html. Now, I want it such that when a user gets **logged in** using username & password through **Intro Page** then they get navigated to **ShinyDashboard**. Basically, the Intro/Login Page should have an HTML template theme and other parts of the app have a ShinyDashboard theme. Could you please suggest any tips or examples which will help me achieve the same?

**EDIT :**
Here the piece of code which I have written:

## ui

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

tagList(
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",href="style.css")
  )
),
htmlTemplate("htmlpage.html",  
uilogin = uiOutput("uiLogin"),
textpass = textOutput("pass")
),

obs = div(class = "span4", uiOutput("obs")),
distplot = div(class = "span8", plotOutput("distPlot"))

))
```

## server

```
Logged = FALSE;

PASSWORD <- data.frame(Brukernavn = c("Windows","Ubuntu"), Passord =   c("25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad","81b073de9370ea873f548e31b8adc081"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
source("www/Login.R",  local = TRUE)

observe({
if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
  output$obs <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                min = 10000, max = 90000, 
                value = 50000, step = 10000)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- NULL
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist, breaks = 100, main = paste("Your password:", input$passwd))
  })
 }
 })
 })
```

## Login Part

```
USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)

passwdInput <- function(inputId, label) {
tagList(
tags$label(label),
tags$input(id = inputId, type="password", value="")
)
}

output$uiLogin <- renderUI({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
wellPanel(
  textInput("userName", "User Name:"),
  passwdInput("passwd", "Pass word:"),
  br(),
  actionButton("Login", "Log in")
)
}
})

output$pass <- renderText({  
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
if (input$Login > 0) {
  Username <- isolate(input$userName)
  Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
  Id.username <- which(PASSWORD$Brukernavn == Username)
  Id.password <- which(PASSWORD$Passord    == Password)
  if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
    if (Id.username == Id.password) {
      USER$Logged <- TRUE
    } 
  } else  {
    "User name or password failed!"
  }
  } 
  }
  }
  })


  output$uiTest <- renderUI({
  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
  
  # TextImput for Username and Password
  textInput("username", label = h4("Username"), value = "Enter     Username..."),
  textInput("password", label = h4("Password"), value = "Enter  Password..."),
  
  # Log in Button
  actionButton("action", label = "Log in")
  
  )
 )
 })
```

Also, there is HTML file- *htmlpage.html* which is a Intro page. Now, Using the above code everything is working fine. Now, I need when the user login through the Into page (HTML page in shiny), the charts (obs,displot) gets opened in the *shinydashboard* User Interface.Currently, **displot** is getting displayed in HTML theme UI.

Is there a way where I can have my Intro (Login Page) in HTML theme and other parts of app in ShinyDashboard Theme.

Comment: Could you please let me know the reason for downvote as my question seems to be clear as I m looking to have multiple themes in my R Shiny App.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should focus your question more narrowly on a specific problem, show your code, etc.

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks Hack. I have written my piece of code and have tried to explain the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using *renderUI,renderMenu, uioutput* functions. Here is the part of code to achieve the asked query.

## ui

```
shinyUI(
 dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
   dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id="sidebartabs",menuItemOutput("side"))),
     dashboardBody(

   uiOutput("page")

  )
)
)
```

## server

```
observe({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE){

output$page <- renderUI({

  # Integration of Custom HTML Page with login page

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

htmlTemplate("htmlpage.html",

     uilogin = loginpanel()
    )

  ))
})
}
if (USER$Logged == TRUE){    

output$side <- renderMenu({
  inp$sidebarpanel
})

isolate({updateTabItems(session, "sidebartabs")})

output$page <- renderUI({
  inp$main      
})
}})
```

## htmlpage

Include *{{ uilogin }}* in body tag